# AwsS3Adapter' not found

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, composer-php

Class 'League\Flysystem\AwsS3v3\AwsS3Adapter' not found (View: /home/ravenan/laravel_app/resources/views/components/user-homepage/user-homepage-active-listings-card.blade.php)

My amazon S3 works perfectly on localhost but when applied on a live host powered by Hostgator, I experience the error above. I have visited a number of threads and followed several instructions such as:

```
Delete composer.lock
composer require league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 ~1.0
composer require league/flysystem-rackspace ~1.0
```

but keep experiencing the same problem. My PHP version on my live host is version 7.3.33 whilst my local host is 7.4.29. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Deleting the lock file and then requiring new packages on a production system sounds like a pretty bad idea. How do you deploy your application?

Comment: "My PHP version on my live host is version 7.3.33" - that sounds like a horrible idea. PHP 7.3 is out of support since nearly a year. Also, why not use the same version in your development machine when you can't update the production system?

Comment: Hi Nico, thanks for your advice. I updated my PHP per your recommendations. The problem was that the composer files were being installed in a different location to where I thought they were being installed but this has been solved now. Thank you.